# Por qué el método toFixed provoca NaN

Tags: javascript

*Tengo este código, si el valor total está vacio le coloca en 0, pero si aproximo los decimales con **`toFixed`**, envez de no usar toFixed(y no aproximarlo), no puedo dejarlo en cero como **predeterminado**, lo deja en `NaN`, por qué?*

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  
 var cantidad = document.getElementById('c'),
     precio = 1.4,
     total = document.getElementById('total');
  
  cantidad.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    total.value = (1.4 * parseInt(cantidad.value,10)).toFixed(2) || 0;
  }); // Si quitas el .toFixed() , sí lo deja como predeterminado en 0, por qué sucede esto ? y cómo solucionarlo?
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  

<input type="Number" placeHolder="Cantidad" id="c">

<input type="Number" placeholder="Precio unitario: 1.4 USD" readonly>
  <hr>
<input type="text" readonly placeHolder="Valor total" id="total">
  
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Si quitas** el `toFixed()` , **sí lo deja como predeterminado en 0,** por qué sucede esto ? y cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: En mi navegador "falla" cuando coloco usando separador decimal que no sea "." (punto); verifica cual es el separador de decimales que corresponde a tu caso. De hecho con "." me marca en color rojo el espacio para `c` pero si pongo "," (ejm: 1,5) coloca el `NaN` con "." (ejem: 1.5 solo se marca en rojo) no coloca el `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando tienes un valor vacío en el input como ya sabrás, este retorna un string vacío `''`. Convertir un valor así utilizando `parseInt` o cualquier otro valor inválido (que no sea un entero válido) retorna `NaN`. Hasta aquí creo que lo entiendes, el problema es que estas utilizando `toFixed` sobre ese valor `NaN`, `toFixed` lo que hace es tomar un valor `number`, redondear el numero, dejar solo la cantidad los decimales que le indiques y te retorna ese valor como un string, es decir, si le pasamos por ejemplo `14.0567` y aplicamos `toFixed(2)` me retornará `'14.06'`.

`NaN` es de tipo `number` y por lo tanto puedes utilizar su método `toFixed` esto causa que te retorne el valor `'NaN'` como string y siendo un string no vacío su valor en el `or (||)` es `true` y por lo tanto te retorna ese valor y no 0.

Comment: Gracias gerardo, lo solucioné gracias a esto con: includes(NaN)